# Running Azure DevOps Pipelines Tasks on Linux VMs with Azure Active Directory

Tags: linux, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pam

I am trying to run tasks remotely on a Linux-based VM (CentOS) using Azure DevOps Pipelines.  The VM is secured with Azure Active Directory authentication.

I can interactively log in with the device code prompt, but that is obviously difficult to automate.  I tried creating an SSH key and using an SSH service connection, but `SSH@0` task fails with this in the `/var/log/secure` file:

```
Mar 17 22:08:52 centos-vm sshd[5817]: fatal: Access denied for user vm.user@myorg.onmicrosoft.com by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

Is there a way to connect a pipeline with the Linux VM for automated setup?  I will need the ability to run commands remotely and to transfer files.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you deploy an agent on the VM? Could you share your pipeline settings and the entire log?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's all the logging available in `/var/log/secure`.  The next two lines look like the pipeline agent disconnecting.  In terms of steps, I followed this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/login-using-aad#install-the-azure-ad-login-vm-extension.  Then created users in AAD and assigned the "Virtual Machine Administrator Login" role.  While logged in to the Linux VM with AAD credentials (+device code), I created an SSH key, changed authorized_keys to 600 permissions, and created an SSH service connection for the pipeline.

Comment: Could you share your pipeline settings and the entire log?

Comment: Hi @CeceDong-MSFT, sorry, still a little new to the Azure world.  What type of logs and which pipeline settings would you like to see?  The YAML, the service connection details, the system diagnostic logging for the pipeline, or authentication log, etc.?

Comment: Do you create the pipeline in Azure DevOps (https://dev.azure.com/xxxx)? If yes, share the YAML and the pipeline run log.